# In vb.net, I can't get my DirectoryInfo function to work properly

Tags: vb.net

I'm trying to perform file deletion but only on files that don't exist in a list.

Example:

```
Dim FilesToKeep As List(Of String) = MyFunctionThatPopulatesTheList
```

The FilesToKeep list consists of the filenames.

Here is where I'm having trouble, as these clause functions throw me off big-time.

```
Dim filesToDelete

filesToDelete = New DirectoryInfo(FilePath) _
    .GetFiles("*", SearchOption.AllDirectories) _
    .Where(Function(f) Not f.Attributes.HasFlag(FileAttributes.Hidden)) _
    .Where(Function(f) Not FilesToKeep.ToString.Contains(f.Name)) _
    .[Select](Function(f) New FileCollectionForDelete(f)).ToArray()
```

Two things I'm trying to do if you look at the bottom two lines of the DirectoryInfo function. I only want the files that do not exist in the FilesToKeep list. The second, is just a helper where I'm storing the information about the file.

But as it stands, filesToDelete returns every single file.

Thank you for your help.

=========== EDIT =============

After comments, I gave it another shot, but curious if anyone can offer opinion on stability of this function.

First, I created another variable called FilesToKeep2

```
Dim FilesToKeep2 As String = String.Join(",", FilesTOKeep.ToArray())
```

And my function I left how it was, as it isn't comparing the entire path, note the (f.Name).

So right now this seems to be working properly, but worried about gotcha's later on.

Would this function be as solid as iterating through each one individually?

Comment: Try removing the Where clauses and then adding them back in one by one and see what you get.

Comment: Isn't it matter of full path vs filename issue? Maybe `FilesToKeep` have filename with full path, while `f.Name` only filename?

Comment: @KonradKokosa Good idea... trying that now.

Comment: @KonradKokosa Please take a look at my edited post. I think I have it working, but not convinced it's foolproof. Thank you for your help.

Comment: Happy to help. For me this query looks quite foolproof. You should only check if `FilesToKeep` is not null probably.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is this expression:

```
Function(f) Not FilesToKeep.ToString.Contains(f.Name)
```

The type of the `FilesToKeep` object is a `List(Of String)`. Calling `ToString` on a `List(Of String)` returns the name of the type. Just remove that part of the expression and you'll be fine:

```
Function(f) Not FilesToKeep.Contains(f.Name)
```

Also, I think you're overthinking things with the final `.Select()`. Skip that (and the `.ToArray()` call) entirely.

Final code:

```
Dim FilesToKeep As List(Of String) = MyFunctionThatPopulatesTheList()    

Dim filesToDelete = (New DirectoryInfo(FilePath)).GetFiles("*", SearchOption.AllDirectories).
    Where(Function(f) Not f.Attributes.HasFlag(FileAttributes.Hidden)).
    Where(Function(f) Not FilesToKeep.Contains(f.Name))

For Each fileName As String In filesToDelete
     File.Delete(fileName)
Next
```

Regarding your edit: you're *probably* fine with that edit. However, you should know that commas are *legal* in file names, and therefore it's *possible* to create files that should be deleted, but will still match your string. For best results here, at least use a delimiter character that's not legal in file names.